# Where did [advertising-inquiry] go? I miss it so much

Tags: support, meta

The [[advertising-inquiry]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising-inquiry) tag was a very funny piece of meta.  And it's not been there for a month...

What I want to ask is where did it go?  Why has it disappeared?  Does it have anything to do with VC funding?

Edit:  Let me be clear.  This world has an unlimited supply of idiots.  They couldn't have just stopped mailing the address!  Even Einstein said, "two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the the universe."  So I think there's a conspiracy behind this.  And I need the answers!

Comment: I've never answered one, but have taken guilty pleasure from the questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've been meaning to ask the same thing!

Hopefully, Alex wasn't put off by the [hostile reception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41295/advertising-inquiry-the-programmer-who-answer) a few weeks ago (meanwhile deleted)?

I'm pretty sure the vast majority here appreciates `advertising-inquiry`.

Comment: By the way the last inquiry was a piece of humorous art.

Comment: And, by the way II, "last" and "latest" are the same word in Russian. :-\